# print only customfields in whmcs API

Tags: php

i manipulate whmcs API to search for a DOC and print results.

```
         <?php
 /* *** WHMCS XML API Sample Code *** */ 
  $clientId = $_POST['clienteId'];

  $url = "https://westhost.com.br/painel/includes/api.php"; # URL  to.     WHMCS API file goes here
 $username = "root"; # Admin username goes here
 $password = "sadsadsadsa"; # Admin password goes here

  $postfields = array();
$postfields["username"] = $username;
$postfields["password"] = md5($password);
$postfields["action"] = "getclientsdetailsbydoc";
 $postfields["clientDoc"] = $clientId;
$postfields["stats"] = false;
 $postfields["responsetype"] = "xml";

 query_string = "";
 foreach ($postfields AS $k=>$v) $query_string .= "$k=".urlencode($v)."&";

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
 if (curl_error($ch) || !$xml) $xml = '<whmcsapi><result>error</result>'.
  curl_errno($ch).' - '.curl_error($ch).'</curlerror></whmcsapi>';
 curl_close($ch);


 $arr = whmcsapi_xml_parser($xml); # Parse XML

 if( isset($_POST['Pesquisar']) ) {
echo '<pre>'; print_r($arr); echo '</pre>'; # Output XML Response as    ArraY

}
 ?>
```

And the Result is Above,  How Can I tell XML to ONLY SHOW [FIRSTNAME [LASTNAME] and CUSTOMFIELDS1 in the Print                                              ..................................................................................

```
       Array
 (
[WHMCSAPI] => Array
    (
        [ACTION] => getclientsdetailsbydoc
        [RESULT] => success
        [CLIENT] => Array
            (
                [USERID] => 3139
                [ID] => 3139
                [UUID] => 248d425a-04b1-452c-ab46-428fbb9c44f1
                [FIRSTNAME] => Luiz Henrique
                [LASTNAME] => A de Souza
                [FULLNAME] => Luiz Henrique A de Souza
                [COMPANYNAME] => lionconsultoria
                [EMAIL] => luizhas@gmail.com
                [ADDRESS1] => Cabo Frio
                [ADDRESS2] => 
                [CITY] => Cabo Frio
                [FULLSTATE] => RJ
                [STATE] => RJ
                [POSTCODE] => 28970000

                    [CUSTOMFIELDS1] => 28391656764
                    [CUSTOMFIELDS] => Array
                    (
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this probably works:

```
echo $arr['WHMCSAPI']['CLIENT']['FIRSTNAME']
echo $arr['WHMCSAPI']['CLIENT']['LASTNAME']
echo $arr['WHMCSAPI']['CLIENT']['CUSTOMFIELDS1']
```